# How do I connect vertices to edges?

Tags: vertices, edges

I'm following a tutorial by Blenderguru, but I hit a problem with the mesh.

I need to connect a vertice to another, but there are several edges between them and I would like there to be vertices on all the edges all the way.

[image]

How do I connect vertices to an edge? Do you know, please let me know ^^, 
Thank you =D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option would be to select both vertices you want to connect and press <kbd>J</kbd> which will connect vertices and cut through edges along the way, BUT this option sometimes does not take the path you want.

You could also press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> (loop cut) to cut through the edges you mentioned between the two vertices, this will though not go all the way to the 2 vertices. Then you can select the vertex you want to connect on one side and connect it with the closest one generated by the loop cut, same for the other side.

Lastly you can use the knife tool <kbd>K</kbd> and click on the first and then on the last vertex, in the view like in the picture it might be a bit hard to select the lower vertex though, for that you can start the cut and rotate the view to select the lower vertex.
Press <kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm the cut.

Visual version:

[image]

Comment: I fixed it right away with the first suggestion :D Aaaah, thank you sooo much Xylvier!! <3

Comment: Happy to help, could you be so kind and accept the answer then ;)

Comment: Of course Xylvier, but how do I that? Sorry, I´m new ^^,

Comment: I myself have yet to ask a question here so i had to check myself XD
[Accept answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Saw your from Norway, så ville bare si tusen hjertelig takk Xylvier! :D

Comment: Gjerne, håper du ha en god tid med Blender.